# import 50k record file

Tags: php

I have a task to import 50k records file import in the database through ajax 
it works for 5k records but when I upload the file which has 50k records in it, after some time it says gateway timeout how can I handle it

Comment: Have you modified you php.ini in any way? For example to increase the maximum execution time?

Comment: yes I have set it to maximum i.e. 0

Comment: Also the maximum file size, etc? I would look into that maybe.

Comment: yes, max file size to 1024M, upload_max_filesize  1024M,memory_limit 1024M

Comment: What is the database? Do you have access to the server console.

Comment: mysql @DilyanTrayanov

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta use the console to import the file, it is easier.
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc. Also this will make the import statement in one transaction, therefor the execution will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Importing 50k in one request is probably a bad idea. If you are able to change the settings ( max upload, max_execution_time ... ) locally, you might have problems doing this in the prod server.
What I suggest is splitting the 50k into slices.
One request imports 1k, on success import next 1k ...

Comment: This should be a comment _at best_

Comment: I dont want to do like this